# Insert concatenated values of two colums in a table into a single column of another table

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation, mysql-error-1292

I have a table that has three columns. They are of type VarChar. I am looking to concatenate the values on first and second column and insert that into the First column of another table.

I used this code

```
insert into table2(cloumn1)
select city+''+Coalesce(zipcode) from table1
```

I get an error

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'london'
```

"London" is the value of the first row and the second row has values like "123.2.4.4"
Both columns are declared as VarChar.

What should I change in the query to get values in the table2 that look like "london 123.2.4.4"  ??

Comment: What is the table structure of `table2`? I am guessing you are trying to insert the result into a column with a `double` datatype.

Comment: Table two has four columns and I am trying to get the value into the first column.

Comment: What is the datatype of that column?

Comment: varchar(). I have allocated enough space.. say varchar(100)

Comment: Still doesnt work. gives the same error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the `CONCAT()` function to concatenate the strings:

```
insert into table2(cloumn1)
select CONCAT(city, Coalesce(zipcode, '')) 
from table1
```

And be sure that the datatype of the column you are inserting into is a varchar. If the datatype is a double, then you will receive this error.